# Book or story about a person alone for life on a spaceship. Aliens make a friend

Tags: story-identification, space

Somewhere in the 80s I read a story or book about a person in a ship traveling through space alone. It is unlikely he will ever get to meet humans again. He has at a point someone to correspond with but as their ships divert away the lags between him sending a message and receiving grow much too long. Further on he meets an alien civilization who takes pity on him and construct a flawed female puppet for him based on porno that he has in the ship. It is all very lonely but memorable. If you have an idea which story it is, I would want to read it again.

Comment: Where did you read it, in an anthology, a schoolbook, a magazine?